# translating Unicode characters from input

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have a string with unicode characters that I need to decode. When I hardcode the string into python it seems to work. However, if I get it through an input, it doesn't translate. For example,

```
input_0 = input() #f\u00eate
print(input_0) # prints f\u00eate
word = "f\u00eate"
print(word) # prints fête
```

How could I turn the Unicode parts of the string from the input into regular characters? I have tried using str(word) too.

Comment: What's providing the input? Are you doing it manually, or is there some other system that's piping it in or something? If it's another system, what format is it providing exactly? This might be a JS-style escape, for example. If you're doing it manually, why aren't you simply writing the characters? Does your keyboard not support them or something? BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but - why don't you simply type in fête?

Comment: Thanks! Fête was just an example. It was mainly curiosity that got me to ask the question. I understand why it would work like that, but I wanted to see if there was an easier way rather than creating a function. I have a microcontroller acting as a keyboard typing inputs in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get from `input()` is a raw-string which means you don't have escape sequence they are literal characters. `\u00ea` is 6 characters.

You should encode it with `"raw-unicode-escape"` and then decode it with `"unicode-escape"`:

```py
input_0 = input()  # f\u00eate
print(input_0.encode("raw-unicode-escape").decode("unicode-escape"))
```

Explanation for these two encodings: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings